# How can i drop row using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know, many many similar questions asked many many times (many is two times). But I can't figure out how can I do this in my case. It does not take any effect and I don't know why.

code:

```
default_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

start_urls = []
if os.path.exists(f'{default_path}/amazon_permalink_error.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{default_path}/amazon_permalink_error.csv')
    if len(df) > 0:
        all_completedISBN = pd.read_csv(f'{default_path}/amazon_permalink.csv')['ISBN'].to_list()
        for i in range(len(df)):
            if df.iloc[i]['sku'].split('/')[-1] not in all_completedISBN:
                start_urls.append(df.iloc[i]['sku'])
            else:
                df.drop(i)
    else:
        os.remove(f'{default_path}/amazon_permalink_error.csv')
```

`amazon_permalink_error.csv`:

```
sku
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B085K647FM
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07MTMCNLX
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07WSK5W7V
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B089T73ZB9
```

`amazon_permalink.csv`

```
ISBN,PERMALINK,Main Link,Brand,Price
B085K647FM,Razer-Raptor-Gaming-Monitor-Compatible,https://www.amazon.com/Razer-Raptor-Gaming-Monitor-Compatible/dp/B085K647FM,Razer,$619.95
B085K647FM,Razer-Raptor-Gaming-Monitor-Compatible,https://www.amazon.com/Razer-Raptor-Gaming-Monitor-Compatible/dp/B085K647FM,Razer,$619.95
B0959Y663R,Razer-Raptor-Gaming-Monitor-Compatible,https://www.amazon.com/Razer-Raptor-Gaming-Monitor-Compatible/dp/B0959Y663R,Razer,$797.49
B087N4LQPN,ALIENWARE-AW2521HF-24-5-Gaming-Monitor,https://www.amazon.com/ALIENWARE-AW2521HF-24-5-Gaming-Monitor/dp/B087N4LQPN,Alienware,
```

When I print:
`print(len(start_urls))` it shows me `943` and total length of error file is `1134`, so it means it is working but when I'm dropping which is `in` and print at last `print(len(df))` it shows `1133` but it should show 943.

Comment: This worked for me : ```print(df[df.sku.isin(start_urls)])```

Answer (score 0):

You are dropping the row from pandas using the `drop` method but not updating the variable's data. Use `inplace=True` for the drop method to solve your query

```
df.drop(i, inplace=True)
```